# Changing values of a column in a dataframe during an iteration through a different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have the following Dataframe:

```
id questionCode answer difficulty
1  3t4          False   0
2  3t4          True    0
3  3t5          False   0
4  3t6          True    0
5  3t4          False   0
```

I want the difficulty to change by one point based on how often the question was answered correctly or incorrectly. The difficulty is already 0 (that is, very easy), and the question keeps being answered correctly, it can't go below 0.

So in this case, the output would be:

```
    id questionCode answer difficulty
    1  3t4          False   1
    2  3t4          True    1
    3  3t5          False   1
    4  3t6          True    0
    5  3t4          False   1
```

This is because `3t4` was answered one time correctly and two times incorrectly, `3t5` was answered one time incorrectly and `3t6` was answered one time correctly. Although not very elegant, the "final difficulty result" appears in every row once the code is done.

It would be something like (in pseudocode):

```
for rank in difficulty:
    if answer==False:
        rank = rank + 1
    else:
        if rank == 0:
            continue
        else:
            rank = rank - 1
```

But how can I involve `questionCode` in all this, and keep the desired difficulty score per each question in a new dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### One-liner

Calling `df` to the above dataframe, a one-line solution would be:

```py
df.difficulty = \
    (df.questionCode.map({'3t4':1, '3t5':1, '3t6':-1}) + df.difficulty).clip(lower=0)
```

### Explanation

First, it maps each of the `questionCode` options into its numeric equivalent, setting +1 for the cases where a question was failed (`'3t4'` and `'3t5'`) and - `for the cases where the question was answered correctly (`'3t6'`):

```py
df_update = df.questionCode.map({'3t4':1, '3t5':1, '3t6':-1})
#   0    1
#   1    1
#   2    1
#   3   -1
#   4    1
```

Then, we add it to the existing values and limit it to a minimum of `0`:

```py
df.difficulty = (df.difficulty + df_update).clip(lower=0)
#   0    1
#   1    1
#   2    1
#   3    0
#   4    1
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this possible if the dataframe was huge, with thousands of rows?

Comment: Cute comment. A huge dataset should have hundreds of thousands or even millions of rows. A few thousands should be extremely fast and easy to compute this way. There are no intermediate variables (in the one liner), and the functions are applied in a *functional programming* style, thus this should be extremely scalable.